# How to pass variables from rails controller to AngularJs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a rails controller for recipes. I have added some additional variable called *@recID*. I am able to access this variable successfully  in index.json.jbuilder.

I can't figure out how to access it in my app.js (which is angular controller file).

My research has covered:

- [How can i pass a scope variable from controller to directive in angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36028750/how-can-i-pass-a-scope-variable-from-controller-to-directive-in-angular-js)
- [How can controller talk to a directive in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282828/how-can-controller-talk-to-a-directive-in-angularjs)

and many other google searches.

Here is a code snippet in from app.js:

```
$scope.search = function(keywords) {
  return $location.path("/").search('keywords', keywords);
};
// query = $resource('/', {query: "query"});
// query =  $resource('/recipes/:recipeId', {

query =  $resource('/', {
  query: "@recID",
  format: 'json'
});
console.log ("About to write to log query=" + query);
// alert ("query =<" + query + ">");
Recipe = $resource('/recipes/:recipeId', {
  recipeId: "@id",
  format: 'json'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try using gon.gon is a gemused to pass data to js.first you need to install gon.then in your controller you can specify

```
gon.variable_name = variable_value
```

in your js

```
gon.variable_name
```

https://github.com/gazay/gon
https://gist.github.com/shicholas/5937417

Answer (score 0):

You can set some hidden_field in the HTML with controller variable value and fetch this value in app.js using DOM selector.